# jQuery html() and &nbsp; causing an Uncaught error: Syntax error

Tags: jquery

I am trying to loop through a series of TD's and get the contents and append it to a div. I am having an issue with &nbsp;'s. When these are included in the table, I am getting the following error:-

Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression:

I am using the following code:-

```
    var speakerInt = 1;

    $('.oldSpeakerTable tr').each(function(){
        var speakerID = "speakerID" + speakerInt;
        var newDiv = "<div id='" + speakerID + "' class='speakerInfo'></div>";
        $(newDiv).appendTo($('#speakerContainer'));
        speakerID = "#" + speakerID;

            $.each(this.cells, function(){
                var newHTMLRow = $(this).html();
                $(newHTMLRow).appendTo($(speakerID))
            });
        speakerInt++;
    })
```

If anyone can shed some light on this, I would appreciate it. I have tried to remove the &nbsp; with a replace function:-

```
    newHTMLRow.html(newHTMLRow.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''));
```

But this hasn't helped. An example of the tr follows.

```
<tr>
    <td width="110" valign="top">
        <img src="/image.php?acc=5617&amp;id=336283&amp;width=100" style="border:0px;float:left;border:0px;">
    </td>
    <td valign="top">
        <a href="javascript:load_url('/ereg/popups/speakerdetails.php?eventid=103117&speakerid=199393','Jeffrey R. Currie','400','400');">
        <b>Jeffrey R. Currie</b></a><br>
        Gobal Head of Commodities Research<br>Goldman Sachs
    </td>
</tr>
```

Thanks.

Comment: `var newHTMLRow = $(this).html();` why do you want to convert the selected to html?? try `$(this).clone().appendTo($(speakerID))`

Comment: I don't see any `&nbsp;`s in the example HTML.

Comment: @Cheery - I am trying to get the HTML from within the td and append it to a div. I want to strip out the td. I have found a way to do it using contents().unwrap(). 

Instead of the $.each i use :-

                $(this).find('td').each (function() {
                    var newHTMLRow = $(this);
                    $(newHTMLRow).appendTo($(speakerID))
                });
and then this
        $('.speakerInfo td').each(function(){
            $(this).contents().unwrap();
        })